# How to merge multiple view controllers into a single scrollview.

Tags: swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have built three separate view controllers and would like to merge them into one scrollview, so that when the user scrolls, they can view all the views like as though they are one page.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: How about a vertically scrolling `UIPageViewController`?

Comment: Add the view from each of the view controllers as a subview to the scrollview and setup constraints to position each below the other. i.e `viewController2.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewController.view.bottomAnchor)`

Comment: Create One new view controller add add your viewcontroller as child, Or you can add configure UIPageViewController with your controllr

Answer (score -1):

You can use [ContainerView](https://useyourloaf.com/blog/container-view-controllers/) 
add container views vertically and load your view controllers inside them